# Do native speakers use this type of apposition?

Tags: grammar

I'm not entirely sure if this appositive construction is commonly used by native speakers. 
" This is the deepest, ***if not the deepest***, lakes in Africa."

Answer (score 0):

"This is **one of the deepest**... is current usage.  I think that's what you mean.  (one of the deepest lakes, if not the deepest lake)

Lake Tanganyika is **one of the deepest lakes** in Africa.

Lake Tanganyika is one of the deepest lakes, **if not the deepest lake**, in Africa.

> Lake Tanganyika is an African Great Lake. It is estimated to be the second largest freshwater lake in the world by volume, and the second deepest, in both cases, after only Lake Baikal in Siberia.

Comment: Strictly, 'Lake Tanganyika is one of the deepest lakes, if not the deepest lake, in Africa.'

Comment: @Centaurus and @ Edwin: Thanks for editing and answering the question. But, would it be stylistically proper if we deleted the word "lake"?

Comment: Whatever, there's no apposition in the OP's example.